# Running Processes from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, casperjs

The casper.js code looks like this.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'test.txt';

fs.touch(path);

casper.start('http://www.google.com', function() {
    fs.write(path, this.getHTML(), 'w');
});

casper.run();
```

I'm calling the process like this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\CasperJS\casperjs-casperjs-b4f7669\bin\casperjs", @"C:\casper\casper.js");
```

It works when I run

```
>casperjs casper.js
```

from the command line but not when I try to run it from visual studio. Any ideas why?

Comment: does it give any error? Also, I can assume that code just downloads an HTML and store it on file, why complicate it with external programs when you can just do it in C# with WebClient?

Comment: WebClient can't execute javascript the way a headless browser can. It doesn't give any error, the program runs and closes without showing any text

Comment: Well, I'm not very versed on casper, but `this.getHTML()` will only get the html content sent, no? anyway, that sounds like if the program is running out of it's correct directory, instead of the Start overload accepting two strings use the one which accepts a ProcessStartInfo and set the WorkingDirectory to the correct one, for the command line you posted I assume the correct working directory will be the one where the .js is stored, and then you don't need to pass the full path on the parameters, just pass "casper.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easily fixed by moving the js file into the same directory as my application.exe file. I then added CasperJS to my path so that it can be called without needing to specify the full path. My C# code ended up looking like this.

```
Process.Start("casperjs", "casp.js");
```

Where casperjs is the casperjs program and casp.js is the javascript file I'm trying to run.